# Emails sent by internal user to internal user via Templates being blocked 550 Administrative Lockout

Tags: email

Has anyone seen this issue before?

- If an internal user with email personA@mycompany.com sends an email
  via Salesforce to another @mycompany.com email address in the 'other
  To' section of an email, it is sent back to personA as undeliverable.
- Yet if I have an internal user with different email domain, say
  consultant@consultingcompany.com and they send an email via
  Salesforce to an @mycompany.com email address, it works fine.
- This happens regardless of our 'Sender ID compliance' setting within
  Salesforce

Something in the email server settings that is blocking SF delivered email to their domain from their domain?  I haven't seen this issue before and my client uses an outsourced IT service that doesn't have a lot of Salesforce experience.  What questions should I be asking the IT company about how their internal email is set up?